# Convert json array into List of Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json.net

This is my Json List of Objects array that I stringified and sent to my controller

```
"[{\"Id\":\"fieldone\",\"Name\":\"fieldtwo\"}]"
```

How can I deserialize it in my controller and turn it into a list of Objects again?

Currently this is what I have:

```
var RoleList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleViewModel>(Input.RoleList);
```

and these are my ViewModels

```
public class UserAddRoleListViewModel
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class SampleViewModel
{
    public List<UserAddRoleListViewModel> Test { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment when I run it, I get this error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'App.Data.ViewModels.SampleViewModel' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
```

What should I do to convert this into a list of UserAddRoleListViewModels?

EDIT: Added Controller and Relevant ViewModel

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult VerifyRole(SaveUserNewRoleViewModel Input)
    {
        var RoleList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleViewModel>(Input.RoleList);
        return null;
    }

public class SaveUserNewRoleViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public String RoleId { get; set; }
    public String RoleName { get; set; }
    public String RoleList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your controller definition? Note that, based on your classes, you're expecting JSON like `{ "test": [{ "id": "abc", "name": "def" }] }`

Comment: Based on the error message it looks like you were suppose to do `var RoleList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserAddRoleListViewModel>>(Input.RoleList);`

Comment: you need to provide more details so that a relevant answer can be provided.

Comment: @John I added my controller.

Comment: @Nkosi may I know what other details you need?

Comment: What is inside `RoleList` property ? Is it a valid JSON string ?

Comment: @JianYA The JSON snippet seems incomplete now that the controller has been shown. You should not have to parse JSON manually. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Hi @JameelM, this is what it looks like when I pass another item inside "[{\"Id\":\"fieldone\",\"Name\":\"fieldtwo\"},{\"Id\":\"fieldone1\",\"Name\":\"fieldtwo1\"}]"

Comment: @Nkosi the main thing I'm asking is how can I convert that stringified list into a .net list of objects?

Comment: @JianYA I already showed that in my first comment above, but this just feels like a bigger problem underneath. We'll end up wasting time going back and forth because the details presented, while it may seem clear to you, will not appear so to us looking in.

Comment: @Nkosi your solution was the answer. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the shown JSON array and the error message indicating that you are trying to convert an array to a single object, it looks like you were suppose to do

```
var RoleList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserAddRoleListViewModel>>(Input.RoleList);
```

in order to parser the JSON correctly into a `List<>`

Answer (score 0):

To make the following working

```
var RoleList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleViewModel>(Input.RoleList);
```

your json should be like below

```
"{ Test:[{\"Id\":\"fieldone\",\"Name\":\"fieldtwo\"}] }"
```

Otherwise, for correct result fro your json

```
"[{\"Id\":\"fieldone\",\"Name\":\"fieldtwo\"}]"
```

use below

```
var RoleList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserAddRoleListViewModel>>(Input.RoleList);
```